# Django Template Reverse URL Resolution Not Working

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I have the following in my project's urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^watches/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', list_detail.object_detail, watch_detail, name='watch_detail'),
 )
```

However, the following line in a template returns an error:

```
<li><a href ="{% url 'watch_detail' 1 %}">A link</a></li>
```

It returns this error:

> NoReverseMatch at /watches/
>
> Reverse for ''watch_detail'' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

This confuses me a lot, because if I run "manage.py shell" I get the following results:

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse("watch_detail", args=(1,))
'/watches/1/'
>>>
```

Any suggestions as to what might be wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What's the third parameter you've got in your url conf (`watch_detail`)? Looking at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions), your third parameter should be a dictionary.

Should your conf file read as follows? -

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^watches/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'list_detail.object_detail.watch_detail', name='watch_detail'),
)
```

(that's assuming your view is at `list_detail/object_detail/watch_detail`).

Just to clarify, you can also pass a view function instead of a string path, so your url conf could be written like -

```
from your_app.your_module import watch_detail

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^watches/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', watch_detail, name='watch_detail'),
)
```

Where the second parameter, `watch_detail`, is your view function.

EDIT

If watch_detail really is a parameter then you'll need to include it in the template reverse function -

```
{% url 'watch_detail', 1, watch_detail %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm not sure that solves it. I do not think that my conf file should read as follows, because object_detail is a generic function which takes dictionary watch_detail as an argument. (The third parameter that I've got (watch_detail) is a dictionary.)

Comment: Try adding the watch_detail parameter to your template reverse function. The error message you're getting says the reverse function isn't getting any kwargs. So - {% url 'watch_detail', 1, watch_detail %}

Comment: If you're using namespaces for your apps then don't forget to include that in the url e.g. `{% url 'namespace:viewmethod' %}`